# Carrierwave causes eoferror error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, fog

I have section in admin panel, where admin can crop images of articles.

Cropped images saves only from several tries and often causes EOFError or Broken Pipe exception.

Answer (score 0):

correct answer is update "fog" gem to the version 1.22.0 from 1.1.0